# Process dataframe with lapply and gsub

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, gsub

I have a dataframe with different columns and especially a "commodity_name" column. In this column different commodities are listed, like "wti", "brent", "wheat", "cbot wheat", etc.

Somehow I want to "filter" the column and group the names. So instead of "wti" and "brent" there shall be "group oil". It is also okay for me to have this in a extra column. 
Background Info: I want to group the names and then "dummy" with the dummies library.

I have tested different approaches so far, but none of them worked out. My idea right now ist the following.
Setting up a list of commodities to be included in the "oil" group

```
oil <- list("brent", "gasoline", "heating oil", "nymex heating oil", "nymex wti", "rbob gasoline",  "crude oil", "wti", "unleaded gas", "wti")
```

Setting up a function to prepare the names to be used with gsub. df = dataframe ("df_coded" in this case), findlist = my liste co commodities (oil in this case), replace = groupe name to replace the commodity name ("goil" in this case).

```
grouper <- function(df, findlist, replace){
  string <- df
  find.list <- findlist
  find.string <- paste(unlist(find.list), collapse ="|")

  df <- gsub(find.string, replacement = replace, x = string)
}
```

Finally, I used the grouper function with lapply on my dataframe column ("commodity_name")

```
df_coded$commodity_name <- lapply(df_coded$commodity_name, function(x){grouper(df_coded$commodity_name, oil, "goil")})
```

Now my whole program gets stuck.
There must be an easier / better way for this problem. 
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Here is 1 problem...Look at your `lapply`...you say `lapply(..., function(x)...)` but you never use `x`. Do you mean to say `lapply(df_coded$commodity_name, function(x){grouper(x, oil, "goil")})`?

Comment: Maybe simply `df_coded$commodity_name <- ifelse(df_coded$commodity_name %in% c("brent", "gasoline", etc), "goil", commodity_name)` ?

Comment: @zx8754 
df_coded$commodity_name <- ifelse(df_coded$commodity_name %in% c("brent", "gasoline", etc), "goil", commodity_name) 
does exactly what I wanted it to do! I tried it befor, but maybe I did something wrong, because now it works. 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for loops, maybe simply:

```
oil <- c("wti", "brent", "etc.")

df_coded$commodity_name <- ifelse(df_coded$commodity_name %in% oil),
                                  "goil", df_coded$commodity_name)
```